# How to pass on a value from a jsp to conroller and back to a jsp while using jsps in Apache tiles?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have configured tiles for Spring web project.

The tiles.xml looks as follows

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="template" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp">

        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp  "/>
        <put-attribute name="center" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" /> 
    </definition>

    <definition name="header" extends="template">

        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/ads.jsp" />  
    </definition>

    <definition name="numberResult" extends="template">

        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/numberResult.jsp" />  
    </definition>

    <definition name="nameResult" extends="template">

        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/nameResult.jsp" />  
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

Now my problem is I have an input field titled studentName in header.jsp.

Lets say user enter "abcd" in that input field. I pass it to controller and I return to nameResult.jsp (where now also the page has header.jsp as part of tiles).

I want to fix the following two issues.

1) I want to retain "abcd" in the input field in header.jsp when I return from controller and display it to user in the input field.

2) I also want to use the value "abcd"(which is in header.jsp) from nameResult.jsp for a AJAX request.

header.jsp code

```
<div id="mycontainer">  
    <form method="get" action="number" id="number">
    <!--    <div id="regNoErrorMsgNumber">Only numbers are allowed</div> -->
            <div style="text-align: center;" >
                    <!-- //TODO: Only number, no spaces, no special symbol and 12 digit check-->                

                             <input  width="20" type="text" data-validation="numbers" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="Enter Register Number"> <b>OR</b>       

            </div>

    </form>           

    <form method="post" action="name" id="name">                 
                <input  type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="Enter Student Name"></input>      
            <c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
    </form>                             
</div>
```

Comment: Try using ModelAndView to send the parameter value back to jsp

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming you already have a controller method who return type is ***ModelAndView***. All you need to do is use the ***addObject(parameterName, parameterValue);*** method of ModelAndView and you should be able to get the value back on JSP, and also you will be able to use that value to make your AJAX request

Comment: parth6 Sure, I will try that. Could you also answer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447194/how-do-i-update-a-cforeach-using-ajax-in-spring-project?noredirect=1#comment41537672_26447194